# How to install Comodo Antivirus in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, antivirus

I have installed Comodo Antivirus in Ubuntu 12.04. Now it had installed, but after running it it shows to run a script.

Please help me to install Comodo Antivirus (or suggest any good Antivirus).

Comment: I agree that you generally dont need antivirus for Ubuntu... However as Ubuntu and other distros become more common, more viruses will be written for ubuntu. So be safe on you downloads and install some antivirus.. https://www.comodo.com/home/download/download.php? try this site out and it should help installing comodo. hope this helps

Comment: I would steer clear of Comodo antivirus - it doesn't detect a good portion of Linux bad-guy viruses, and is mostly tuned for Windows viruses.  Personal opinion, as an IT Security person.

Answer (score 3):

First, you really don't need an antivirus for Ubuntu unless you're planning on dealing with windows files and/or systems.

You can download Comodo Antivirus from their [website](http://www.comodo.com/home/download/download.php?prod=antivirus-for-linux&track=3646&key5sk1=1049a9f9bf46143e5c131a15bb0acb1384d1251a&key5sk2=&key5sk3=1385282695000&key5sk4=&key5sk5=1385282672000&key5sk6=3646&key5sk7=1385282700000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=FF250&key6sk3=40&key6sk4=en-us&key6sk5=JO&key6sk6=0&key6sk7=http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php&key6sk8=118800&key6sk9=1440900&key6sk10=false&key6sk11=aa440ee81835b14abc94387d837854f85874cb5f&key6sk12=2034&key7sk1=204398&key1sk1=dt&key1sk2=http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php), and choose your architecture 32bit or 64bit.  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded (probably the Downloads folder), and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

I would recommend ClamAV.  To install run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
sudo freshclam
sudo clamscan
```

Or click [Here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clamav/)

Comment: I have installed Comodo but it shows this(picture on this link):

http://www.flickr.com/photos/94477088@N02/11024379894/in/photostream/

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: I need a antivirus to remove Windows virus.

Comment: Then take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/167539/how-do-i-scan-my-windows-partition-for-viruses-from-ubuntu/167545#167545

Answer (score 1):

1- Download below

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb

2- Use below command to install

```
sudo dpkg --install libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

3- Download

http://cdn.download.comodo.com/cis/download/installs/linux/cav-linux_x64.deb

4- Use below command to set up

```
sudo dpkg --install cav-linux_x64.deb
```

5- Run the below script

```
sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh
```

6 - You will find a shortcut on disktop for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Install Comodo Antivirus For Linux 1.1 X86-64 On Ubuntu 12.10 - Desktop X86-64:

Step #1
Download the `.deb` file from: "http://download.comodo.com/cavmgl/download/installs/1000/standalone/cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb".

Step #2
Double click the `.deb` file to open it the Ubuntu Software Center, then click "Install".

Step #3
In terminal type: `sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh`.

Comment: Comodo does not support 12.10 yet, List of supported OS from comodo web page: Supported Operating Systems

32 and 64 bit:

    Ubuntu 12.04
    Red Hat Enterprise
    Linux Server 5.9, 6.3
    Fedora 17
    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11
    OpenSUSE Linux 12.1
    Debian 6.0
    CentOS 5.9, 6.2
    Mint 13
    CentOS 5.8, 6.2

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04 the command to run the script begins with "sudo" because you have to run the script with administration privileges.

The command you type out in the terminal is: `sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh`

Then enter your password.  Then just keep clicking "enter" to scroll down and see the "more" of the EULA, until you get to where it tells you Comodo has been successfully installed and the terminal prompts you for a fresh command for something else.  Now close the terminal and you are done.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1 st download from site antivirus..
then unpack it with:

- `sudo dpkg -i cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb`
- `sudo apt-get install clamav`
- `sudo apt-get -f install`
- `sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh`

the last provides a license agreement..

Answer (score 0):

To iterate for the Comodo antivirus `libssl` issue, do the following:

- Open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file as root:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- Enter the following:

  ```
  ## COMODO CAV-LINUX REPOSITORY
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe;
  ```
- Then run:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8
  ```
- Retry running:

  ```
  gdebi cav-linux_x64.deb
  ```

[image: antivirus running]